# Message body disappear after hash symbol in flutter url_launcher when send a SMS

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I'm using url_launcher in flutter to send SMS.

But there are hash symbols in my message body, and after hash symbols ,all message is disappear.

For example,

```
String uri= 'sms:$phoneNumber?body=123##456';

    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
        await launch(uri);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $uri';
      }
    }
```

The number '456' is disappear on SMS.

How to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "#" with "%23"

```
String uri= 'sms:$phoneNumber?body=123%23%23456';
```

Comment: Thx ! It's work. I'll do my study on encode after this one.